# file upload fail in php

Tags: php, html

When I put this:

```
 <input name="image" type="file" value="Browse" />
```

I get a weird text in hebrew..saying "choose file" and next to it is written "file wasnt chosen", how do I make the text in english..how do I override the default?

Also how do I put a predetermined picture in my database.. do I go to a field and click As defined than put :

```
"Images/Untitled-1.png"
```

The image folder than the image name?

Comment: I think that's OS dependent which language is shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your localization settings....no overriding here, it's the OS that does this for you.

Comment: I am using xp.. and dreamweaver.. How can I change that?

Comment: WinXP or Dreamweaver issue => ask on SuperUser

Comment: Dreamweaver? Okay....anyway, it's in your OS like I said. A simple search action could have helped you out: http://dev.ektron.com/kb_article.aspx?id=5982